# Can't install lyx due to libboost_regex.so.1.53.0 not present in OpenSuse

Tags: lyx

I am trying to install lyx in opensuse with

```
   sudo zypper in lyx
```

However, I get the following error

```
Problem: nothing provides libboost_regex.so.1.53.0()(64bit) needed by lyx-2.1.3-109.1.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install lyx-2.1.3-109.1.x86_64
 Solution 2: break lyx-2.1.3-109.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies
```

Now, I have 1.54 installed and I have downloaded 1.53 and installed it, and also added this older one to the path to try and find it, however the same error message shows up